# Trying to display Vietnamese characters with php

Tags: php, encoding

When I try to display Vietnamese characters with the following code:

```
<?php

$str = "Nghệ thuật cắm hoa vải";

//echo utf8_encode(html_entity_decode(($str)));
echo html_entity_decode($str);

//echo $str;

?>
```

I get Ngh�? thu�?t c??m hoa va?i as a result.
Tried several option but couldn't make it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the PHP script encoded in UTF-8?  If it is, send a header indicating so:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Alternatively, do:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($string, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: @yken Then probably your PHP file is not saved in UTF-8. Make sure you save it as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: you are really my my my my SAVIOR. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: http://codepad.org/uTmORRmz

Does your browser support Unicode?

Comment: Yes, it is. I also see it on the code pad, but when I run it locally it doesn't work. I using wamp for my php, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try testing:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```